# java get last words from string

Tags: java

How would I go about getting `currentname` from this string?

```
[{"name":"fra"},{"name":"Ue","changedToAt":1447121046000},
{"name":"Nn","changedToAt":1463698483000},
{"name":"currentname","changedToAt":1473109797000}]
```

As well as another string like this

```
[{"name":"fra"},{"name":"Ue","changedToAt":1447121046000},
{"name":"currentname","changedToAt":1473109797000}]
```

or even this

```
[{"name":"fra"},{"name":"currentname","changedToAt":1447121046000}]
```

or even this

```
[{"name":"currentname"}]
```

`currentname` is a variable that is not always the same one day it could be `"jim"` another day `"max"`  please help

Comment: Use a JSON parser.

Comment: Looks like you are dealing with a sequence of values and you want the last one.

Comment: Or the one with the largest timestamp?

Comment: the one with the biggest time stamp however if someone never changes their name then they wont have a time stamp so it would just be [{"name":"currentname"}]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to parse the string you would end up with a structure like:

```
class NameChange {
    private final String name;
    private final Date timeOfChange;
}

List<NameChange> nameChanges;
```

Using Java 8 you could get the current name using:

```
Optional<String> currentName = nameChanges.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(NameChange::getTimeOfChange))
    .map(NameChange::getName);
```

It returns an `Optional` to allow for the possibility that the list has no names in it.

If you are using gson to parse then it's even easier:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Arrays.stream(gson.fromJson(input, NameChange[].class))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [regular expression](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm), with pattern like this

```
String pattern="\"name\":\"([a-zA-Z]+)\"((,\"changedToAt\":[0-9]+\}\])|(\}\]))";
```

The desired result will be in `group[1]`

See Example for all your given samples here:

http://fiddle.re/atkvba
(just push the Java button)